# Error al comprobar usuario en BBDD

Tags: php

estoy desarrollando una web que al meter el nombre de usuario quiero saber si existe o no.
Para ello mediante js recojo la variable del input y la envio vía POST al PHP

```
jQuery(function ($) {
$('#id_del_referido').blur(function(){

    $('#Info').html('<img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/loader.gif" alt="" />').fadeOut(1000);

    var patrocinador = $('#id_del_referido').val();     
    var dataString =patrocinador;

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/wp-content/themes/divi-hijo/comprobacion_patro.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#Info').fadeIn(1000).html(data);
            //alert(data);
        }
    });
});              
});
```

Una vez tenemos el valor del input lo envió mediante post al php

Os dejo el codigo completo de php

```
<?php
//variables y conexion mysql
$hostname="localhost";
$username="myinvestpa";
$password="jPd4qB06";
$dbname="investpainbbdd";
$patro=$_POST['patrocinador'];
$conn = mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password) or die ("<html><script     language='JavaScript'>alert('Unable to connect to database! Please try again later.'),history.go(-1)</script></html>");
mysqli_select_db($conn,$dbname);

//Realizamos la consulta sql

$query = "SELECT * FROM wp_users where user_nicename = '".$patro."'";
$results = mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die('ok');


  if(mysqli_num_rows(@$results) != 0){
    echo '<div id="Error">ID de patrocinador Correcto</div>';
  }
 if(mysqli_num_rows(@$results) == 0){
    echo '<div id="Succes">ID de patrocinador Incorrecto</div>';
 }
 ?>
```

El problema es que al hacer la prueba siempre me da que el usuario es incorrecto. alguna idea o si el código esta mal?

Comment: el envió de la varaible y demas esta bien, no hay que concatenar con . las varaibles y el php?

Comment: ME sigue saliendo valor del patrocinador incorrecto, creo que no se esta pasando bien la variable

Comment: El id del input es el siguiente #id_del_referido, lo que creo que esta sucendiendo que la varaible dataString no se esta pasando correctamente

Comment: He hecho un cambio en el js donde pone el datastring he puesto lo siguiente var dataString =patrocinador;  para que solo coja la varaible patrocinador que es el valor del input

Comment: NO puedo Cambiarlo ya que lo estoy utilizando en wordpress este js y php y wordpress no reconoce el $(function()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como dices no envías bien los parámetros, ya que la estás enviando sin "etiquetar" dicha variable, sería así:

```
 var dataString = {"patrocinador" : patrocinador};
```

Comment: Vale lo probare y os comento

Comment: He cambiado como me has dicho, y me sigue saliendo id de patrocinador incorrecto. y pongo id que si están en la tabla

Comment: deberías probar dos cosas, una que en php llega bien la variable pasada, mediante un echo $patrocinador por ejemplo, y otra probar la consulta select directamente en la base para ver que esta bien construida y no te has comido alguna letra o algo así, porque en el select veo un 'nicename' y bueno no se si es así o es 'nickname'

Comment: Hola Xavi, la consulta esta bien ya que lo primero que hice al ver el error fue eso y si esta bien. en wordpress es nicename. Probare lo del echo a ver si me funciona.

Comment: He hecho el echo $patro y no me sale ninguna variable en ningun sitio.

Comment: Bueno pues eso es que no coge bien la variable, prueba si esta sentencia funciona bien var patrocinador = $('#id_del_referido').val(); mediante un alert o console.log

Comment: si la coge bien, es que no la envía por ajax de forma correcta, puedes probar mediante un print_r($_POST) lo que se envía por ajax, y ver si esta la variable

Comment: Hola Xavier gracias por contestar, primero he creado el alert en el js tanto el normal como el que dicen para jquery el jalert y ninguno me funciona. 2. en el console.log no se como funciona si pudieras guiarme? lo de probar lo de print_r es en el codigo php?

Comment: Bueno Xavier, comentarte he realizado el print del post y me sale lo siguiente: Array ( [patrocionador] => aitor ) creo que el value si lo coge bien.

Comment: disculpame que creo la pifié yo, si has copiado lo que te puse arriba tal cual esta mal porque te pone "patrocionador" y debe poner "patrocinador", lo he editado y corregido.

Comment: prueba a ver.... y me cuentas

Comment: Xavier, perfecto, ahora si me da id de usuario correcto, Genial, que era lo que fallaba?

Comment: Ahora como podría hacer para desabilitar el boton si las filas es = 0?

Comment: Lo que fallaba es lo que te comento más arriba el texto de la solución estaba mal escrito. Y con lo del botón para deshabilitarlo.... creo que podrías en el php devolver sólo el valor de mysqli_num_rows(@$results) y dentro de lo retornado por ajax realizas la validación que tienes de si es correcto o incorrecto y además aquí puedes deshabilitar el botón con el $(elemento).attr("disabled","disabled")

Answer (score 1):

Checa si no es la variable que envías, intenta:

`url: "/wp-content/themes/divi-hijo/comprobacion_patro.php?patro="+patrocinador,`

y en el php `$patro=$_GET['patrocinador'];`

Comment: Francisco gracias por responder pero no sería $_POST ya que lo envió como post? Y porque es patro? no seria patrocinador que es la variable de mi js?

Comment: Francisco, he probado esta solución y también sigue saliendo incorrecto.

Comment: `mysql_connect($servername,$username,$password) or die("Error al conectar " );
  mysql_select_db($dbname) or die ("Error al seleccionar la Base de datos: " );
  
  $r=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_users where user_nicename = '".$patro."'");
  if($r!=NULL){
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
      echo "to do";        
            }
  }`

Comment: este es un método que uso en mi página para comprobar usuarios, igual y te sirve

Comment: Francisco es tal cual lo tengo lo único que me falta es lo del while, si me puedes explicar lo que hace para entenderlo. Gracias

Comment: uso el while por si la consulta arroja múltiples elementos, aunque siempre me hara el primer elemento por el filtro de la consulta